# Weird HyLang dot notation behavior

Tags: hy

Why does the following work:

```
(def session (sessionmaker))
(.configure session :bind engine)
```

...but `(def session (.configure (sessionmaker) :bind engine))` causes my Hy application to throw a `NoneType` `TypeError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `(sessionmaker)` makes a "session" object? Does the `(.configure (sessionmaker) :bind engine)` method call return that session object? Or is it just for a side effect? I suspect it's the latter and just returns `None`. You might be looking for the `doto` form, which lets you configure an object, but then returns it at the end. So the code would be

```
(def session (doto (sessionmaker) (.configure :bind engine)))
```

If you're familiar with Python, the `$ hy --spy` option in the REPL is very useful for understanding how Hy gets compiled.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for your explanation!